# Get bundled products to catalog page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, bundle, catalog

I'm selling cabinets, which are bundles of doors and bodies.

I've added functionality of simple (bodies) and variable (doors) products on page (otions and quantity), but I cant add bundle functionality to the catalog page - there are "Select options" buttons only in each product.

Does anyone know, how to add options of Bundle product to catalog?

I am using Wordpress 4.2.2, WooCommerce 2.3.7 and Product Bundles 4.9.3.

Thank you!

Comment: the bundle products also shown in catalog page ... what do you mean by "Does anyone know, how to add options of Bundle product to catalog?"

Comment: Are you want to show bundle products with new template (design)

Comment: Yes, I've created custom template, which is able to show simple, variable and bundled products. I added functionality (and even ajax) to simple and variable products, but don't know, how to add bundled items in each bundle product on this page.

Comment: Yeah. I just called quick view in each product. It works fine!